# SAPUI5 Fiori app - No navigating targets available

Tags: routes, navigation, sapui5, sap-fiori

I've already seen a post with this same issue, but the answer given was not helpful.

So, on a UI5 standard application extension, I have an Analytical Table which presents results after we press the go button on the smartFilterBar.

Problem is that, when the results show up on the table, each of the results has an active link that when clicked, should show a Popover with another active link which should then navigate to a Fiori GUI application that would display the details of that specific record.

But I always get this graphical error:

[image: Navigation not possible]

When pressing F12 and checking the console, I don't see any errors that I could use for debug and I only see a warning:

[image: F12 - developer Tools: Console logs/warnings]

I would appreciate any help/hint on how to resolve this issue.
P.S: After debugging, I can see that it throws an error even before reaching my extended code. Meaning that, it's breaking on the standard SAP coding.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code here ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define some `targets` in `manifest.json` which match the `route`. For example:

`"targets": {
  "firstTarget": {        // name of the target
  "viewName": "firstView" // name of the view
}},`